# AJAX validation form INSERT into MySQL DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, validation

I working on AJAX and PHP validation program but am unable to write the data to the working mySQL DB.

I'm building a new user member form for a project and have used/made a basic PHP/MySQL form that worked well for me in the past. Now I am trying to upgrade to using AJAX due to the length of my newest form and wanting to make it as easy as possible for those visiting my site as well as always making improvements beyond my current skill level thus always making it harder for myself.

I wound up using the example here
https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/7726-ajax-and-php-sample-chapter-5-ajax-form-validation.pdf

And it works very well. The problem I'm having is extracting the data out to actually place into my DB. I am using a mySQL DB that I know is working and am currently using.

When I add things I believe should work to the validate.class.php page it halts that operation or returns errors. Also adding anything seems to break the AJAX validation. When I try to use the variables else where they come back empty.

I'm not seeing what I am expecting to see when it comes to being able to INSERT from the validated form variables. If this makes any sense.

I mostly have coded embedded projects using microcontrollers and I also like Perl. I have some experience putting together some basic things before using php and mysql and feel comfortable with programming but I'm at a loss on this one. I usually do well jumping in and figuring my way through :)

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Check the error log if you can find any error over there.

Comment: There is very little we can do without seeing any code to debug